# Stop internal read receipts (Outlook 2013)

Tags: email, outlook, exchange-server

User wants to send read receipts with all external emails. I've set up a mailbox rule in Outlook to do the following:

```
Apply this rule after I send the message
notify me when it is read
except if sent to *Bristol* //Dynamic group for office contacts
or except with @"domainname" in the recipient's address
```

To stop read receipts on internal emails I've set a rule with ECP via "Mail Flow" > Rules to:

```
IF 
the message type is *Read receipt*
AND
The sender is located *Inside the organization*
AND
The recipient is located *Inside the organization*
THEN
Delete the message without notifying anyone
```

However it is still requesting read receipts for internal contacts.

Outlook and Exchange 2013

Answer (score 0):

Your rule will only stop the delivery of read recipients not the prompting for which is controlled by a property within the message itself.

You could write a Transport Agent https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877026(v=exchg.150).aspx that could do this by basically processing every message that passes through the Hub (or hubs servers) using the TNEF parser find the PidTagReadReceiptRequested and set it false for those Internal recipients. Probalby the best sample for this type of thing would be http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mstehle/archive/2009/01/13/howto-sample-transport-agent-add-headers-categories-mapi-props-even-uses-a-fork.aspx .

The other way that may work is to Setup a Rule Programatically that using the tagAction http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdoruleaction.htm#RDORuleActionTag . In theory you should be able to modify a MAPI Property with this action but there are complexities around this and I've never use it.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: A little above my skill set, but thanks for the guide.